# What is the most directest way to open() a resource file in a macOS (maybe also iOS) app?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, macos, resources

So I want to open a texture file for `mmap()`ing in Objective-C:

```
const int fd = open([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Texture" ofType:nil] UTF8String], O_RDONLY);
```

I also have a Swift version:

```
let fd = open((NSBundle.mainBundle.path(forResource: "Texture", withExtension: nil) as NSString).UTF8String)
```

But I am not sure if these are the most efficient, and direct ways to perform this task.

What would be the fastest way, that avoids the most unnecessary computation, to simply get a file descriptor from a resource file in an app?

I just want to make sure I'm not using a less optimized version than I need to. I don't know if the answer is different for Objective-C or Swift so I made it both.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Do you have a known bottleneck in your code that needs to be optimized? Why ask the question in two languages?

Comment: You are opening a file on disk. That operation alone is going to dwarf the computation you are doing to get a C string for the system call. And how many times per second are you opening texture files? If it's not "thousands" I wouldn't worry.

Comment: This is a strange mix of high and low level code, even in Objective C. Foundation provides the `NSFileHandle` class as an abstraction over file descriptor ints, `open`, etc. This code looks fine in Swift, but I would probably just use [`FileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle). I'd recommend using `defer`, a class with a `deinit`, or perhaps even a [non-copyable struct](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0390-noncopyable-structs-and-enums.md#proposed-solution) to ensure the `close` doesn't get forgotten